# Merging dataframes (with different date time --monthly vs daily) at the same time applying lagged values to one of the dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, merge, concatenation, lag

I have 2 dataframes I wish to merge:

df1 looks like this:

```
Date          Col1  Col 2  Col 3    Col 4   
    
2016-03     27.57   0.93    28.7    1.57    
2016-04     25.83   0.23    28.34   0.84    
2016-05     24.55   0.27    27.11   0.03
```

df2 looks like this:

```
Date          ColA            

2016-03-21  7.640769230769231   
2016-03-22  7.739720279720279   
2016-03-23  7.577311827956988   
2016-03-24  7.745416666666666
```

As you can see, df1 is a monthly data and df2 is a daily data.
However, I want to merge them in a daily format (following df2) but I also want df1 to be lagged (lag = -30)

This is my desired output:

Output:

```
   Date          ColA              Col1  Col 2  Col 3    Col 4     
      
    2016-03-21  7.640769230769231   25.83   0.23    28.34   0.84
    2016-03-22  7.739720279720279   25.83   0.23    28.34   0.84
    2016-03-23  7.577311827956988   25.83   0.23    28.34   0.84
    2016-03-24  7.745416666666666   25.83   0.23    28.34   0.84


....2016-04-01  xxxxxxxx            24.55   0.27    27.11   0.03
```

I tried this but, they just merge and the lags were not applied.

```
out = (df2.merge(df1.shift(-30), on='Date').axis=1)
```

EDIT: Since I can't make the below suggestions work on my specific problem, what I did is this:

```
   out['Col1']= out['Col1'].shift(7).dropna()
    out = pd.merge_asof(df1, df2,  on = 'Date')
```

This is to lag only 1 column (which I decided to do since most columns have possibility to have different lag times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For merge use [`merge_asof`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html):

```
print (df1)
      Date   Col1  Col 2  Col 3  Col 4
0  2016-03  27.57   0.93  28.70   1.57
1  2016-04  25.83   0.23  28.34   0.84
2  2016-05  24.55   0.27  27.11   0.03

df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'])
print (df1)
        Date   Col1  Col 2  Col 3  Col 4
0 2016-03-01  27.57   0.93  28.70   1.57
1 2016-04-01  25.83   0.23  28.34   0.84
2 2016-05-01  24.55   0.27  27.11   0.03
```

---

```
np.random.seed(20)
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Date': pd.date_range('2016-02-20', periods=20),
                    'ColA': np.random.randint(5, size=20)})
    
print (df2)
         Date  ColA
0  2016-02-20     3
1  2016-02-21     2
2  2016-02-22     4
3  2016-02-23     2
4  2016-02-24     1
5  2016-02-25     4
6  2016-02-26     3
7  2016-02-27     2
8  2016-02-28     0
9  2016-02-29     0
10 2016-03-01     2
11 2016-03-02     2
12 2016-03-03     3
13 2016-03-04     3
14 2016-03-05     0
15 2016-03-06     0
16 2016-03-07     1
17 2016-03-08     2
18 2016-03-09     2
19 2016-03-10     3
```

---

```
#default direction='backward'
df = pd.merge_asof(df2, df1, on='Date', tolerance=pd.Timedelta(7, 'days'))
print (df)
         Date  ColA   Col1  Col 2  Col 3  Col 4
0  2016-02-20     3    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
1  2016-02-21     2    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
2  2016-02-22     4    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
3  2016-02-23     2    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
4  2016-02-24     1    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
5  2016-02-25     4    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
6  2016-02-26     3    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
7  2016-02-27     2    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
8  2016-02-28     0    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
9  2016-02-29     0    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
10 2016-03-01     2  27.57   0.93   28.7   1.57
11 2016-03-02     2  27.57   0.93   28.7   1.57
12 2016-03-03     3  27.57   0.93   28.7   1.57
13 2016-03-04     3  27.57   0.93   28.7   1.57
14 2016-03-05     0  27.57   0.93   28.7   1.57
15 2016-03-06     0  27.57   0.93   28.7   1.57
16 2016-03-07     1  27.57   0.93   28.7   1.57
17 2016-03-08     2  27.57   0.93   28.7   1.57
18 2016-03-09     2    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
19 2016-03-10     3    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
```

---

```
df = pd.merge_asof(df2, df1, on='Date', 
                   tolerance=pd.Timedelta(7, 'days'), direction='forward')
print (df)
         Date  ColA   Col1  Col 2  Col 3  Col 4
0  2016-02-20     3    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
1  2016-02-21     2    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
2  2016-02-22     4    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
3  2016-02-23     2  27.57   0.93   28.7   1.57
4  2016-02-24     1  27.57   0.93   28.7   1.57
5  2016-02-25     4  27.57   0.93   28.7   1.57
6  2016-02-26     3  27.57   0.93   28.7   1.57
7  2016-02-27     2  27.57   0.93   28.7   1.57
8  2016-02-28     0  27.57   0.93   28.7   1.57
9  2016-02-29     0  27.57   0.93   28.7   1.57
10 2016-03-01     2  27.57   0.93   28.7   1.57
11 2016-03-02     2    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
12 2016-03-03     3    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
13 2016-03-04     3    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
14 2016-03-05     0    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
15 2016-03-06     0    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
16 2016-03-07     1    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
17 2016-03-08     2    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
18 2016-03-09     2    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
19 2016-03-10     3    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
```

---

```
df = pd.merge_asof(df2, df1, on='Date', 
                   tolerance=pd.Timedelta(7, 'days'), direction='nearest')
print (df)
         Date  ColA   Col1  Col 2  Col 3  Col 4
0  2016-02-20     3    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
1  2016-02-21     2    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
2  2016-02-22     4    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
3  2016-02-23     2  27.57   0.93   28.7   1.57
4  2016-02-24     1  27.57   0.93   28.7   1.57
5  2016-02-25     4  27.57   0.93   28.7   1.57
6  2016-02-26     3  27.57   0.93   28.7   1.57
7  2016-02-27     2  27.57   0.93   28.7   1.57
8  2016-02-28     0  27.57   0.93   28.7   1.57
9  2016-02-29     0  27.57   0.93   28.7   1.57
10 2016-03-01     2  27.57   0.93   28.7   1.57
11 2016-03-02     2  27.57   0.93   28.7   1.57
12 2016-03-03     3  27.57   0.93   28.7   1.57
13 2016-03-04     3  27.57   0.93   28.7   1.57
14 2016-03-05     0  27.57   0.93   28.7   1.57
15 2016-03-06     0  27.57   0.93   28.7   1.57
16 2016-03-07     1  27.57   0.93   28.7   1.57
17 2016-03-08     2  27.57   0.93   28.7   1.57
18 2016-03-09     2    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
19 2016-03-10     3    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
```

Comment: I actually want to avoid using 'M' since I prefer using days.. like I can lag them by 5 days. 7 days etc.

Comment: @kiwi_kimchi - so need subtract 7 days from months `2016-03` ? So it is `2016-03-01 - 7 days` ?

Comment: So it's like, if df2 is "March"..say I m talking about March 25 2016, and my lag value for df1 is 45 days, therefore March 25 2016 should have df1 value for February--to be specific, Feb 9 2016-- (which is not reflected in my sample data above..but let's say 35.05, 36.01, 36.89, 37.01)

Comment: @kiwi_kimchi - So it means if `2016-03` in df1 it is lagged to `2016-03-01-45days` or `2016-03-31-45days`?

Comment: yes, exactly. that's right

Comment: @kiwi_kimchi - so it means `2016-03-01-45days=2016-01-16`. and then need match with `2016-01-16` in df2 ? Or values between `2016-01-16 - 2016-03-01` from df2 are merged by `2016-03` from df1 ?

Comment: 2016-03-01-45days=2016-01-16 ----this is right. so at df2, 2016-03-01 (ColA is still for 2016-03-01)...but COL 1 TO 4 is df1's 2016-01-16

Comment: @kiwi_kimchi - So it means need merge in tolerance 45 days? Check docs [`merge_asof`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) for tolerance parameter it is is what need.

Comment: I tried yours, but the tolerance only accepts positive values. so the lag value advances to 45 days rather than going back to February 2016..

Comment: @kiwi_kimchi - I add to my answer new sample data, what is expected ouput if lag=7 for data in EDIT?

Comment: @kiwi_kimchi - it seems need `direction='forward'`, added to answer ouputs for different directions parameters.

Comment: hi, thank you so much. for some weird reasons, my merge_as_of is failing (as it doesn't lag the way it should be lagged---just like what your examples above show) so what I did is found on the "EDIT" PART above.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can use:

```
df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'])
df2['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date'])

out = (df2.merge(df1.assign(Date=df1['Date'].sub(pd.DateOffset(months=1))
                                            .dt.to_period('M')),
                 left_on=df2['Date'].dt.to_period('M'), right_on='Date',
                 how='left', suffixes=(None, '_df1'))
      )
```

or:

```
out = (df2.merge(df1.assign(Date=df1['Date'].dt.to_period('M').sub(1)),
                 left_on=df2['Date'].dt.to_period('M'), right_on='Date',
                 how='left', suffixes=(None, '_df1'))
      )
```

output:

```
        Date      ColA Date_df1   Col1  Col 2  Col 3  Col 4
0 2016-03-21  7.640769  2016-03  25.83   0.23  28.34   0.84
1 2016-03-22  7.739720  2016-03  25.83   0.23  28.34   0.84
2 2016-03-23  7.577312  2016-03  25.83   0.23  28.34   0.84
3 2016-03-24  7.745417  2016-03  25.83   0.23  28.34   0.84
```

Comment: I actually want to avoid using 'M' since I prefer using days.. like I can lag them by 5 days. 7 days etc.

Comment: With my first option, you can use the lag you want (e.g., `pd.DateOffset(days=7)`), but in fine if your `df1` only has a YYYY-MM precision, you have to merge on month, no?

Comment: yeah. I have commented on the other answer below (to give more clearance). When i used yours (1st answer), everything became NaNs

Comment: weird, seems to work fine for me, if I use `pd.DateOffset(days=45)`, I get `0 2016-03-21  7.640769  2016-03  24.55   0.27  27.11   0.03` as first row

Comment: For clearance..So it's like, if df2 is "March"..say I m talking about March 25 2016, and my lag value for df1 is 45 days, therefore March 25 2016 should have df1 value for February--to be specific, Feb 9 2016-- (which is not reflected in my sample data above..but let's say 35.05, 36.01, 36.89, 37.01)

Comment: I need df1 to "go back" that's why i'm using negative 45.